# Projection of the force beams on the missile

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, drag, rocket-science

We know that $∑F = ma$ and the forces that affect the rocket is drag and weight and thrust and lift.

I need to know what is the projection of these forces on the three-dimensional world

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert sorry I have edited it

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by "the projection of these forces on the three-dimensional world".

If you are asking about the directions of the forces, then weight acts vertically downwards, thrust will usually act along a tangent to the rocket's direction of travel (although some rockets can vary the direction of thrust to achieve a limited amount of steering) and drag will act in the opposite direction to thrust. A rocket is not designed to generate lift, so lift forces on a rocket will be insignificant compared to the other forces involved.

Comment: Thanks for helping but my question  is the projection of this forces in the three axis this like : the projection of the weight force on the y axis is -mg but on the x axis is 0

Comment: @KhaldounAlHalabi For any force with magnitude $F$ that makes an angle $\theta$ with the vertical, its projection along the vertical axis is $F \cos \theta$ and its projection along the horizontal axis is $F \sin \theta$.